# How to back port a gradle dependency to ant?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm maintaining a legacy app built with a legacy ant built system and have made some changes to it to support the Android M permission changes.

I temporarily created an Android Studio project while evolving the changes and imported all the source files into to. A change I needed to do was to add this dependency to the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"
}
```

Now the source file changes are complete the project now needs to be built using the old legacy ant system. However I don't how to to back-port the gradle dependency.

I tried adding it to the manifest like this:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0" />
```

But when the apk is attempted to be installed there is an error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

How do I add the dependency if not using gradle?

Rewriting the build system to be up to date and using gradle is not an option at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I don't how to to back-port the gradle dependency.

For `support-v4`: "Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`) into your application's project `libs/` directory." (from [the Eclipse setup instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res))

> `<uses-library android:name="com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0" />`

`<uses-library>` is for firmware libraries (e.g., the old Maps V1 stuff) and has nothing to do with Gradle-style dependencies.

> Rewriting the build system to be up to date and using gradle is not an option at this stage.

You have ~77 days, so you had best get working on it. After the end of 2015, do not expect any support for the legacy build system, including standalone Android Support JARs. If you get support after the end of the year, consider it a gift from the heavens.

Comment: Thanks, so if I remove that line from the manifest and copy that jar then everything should be fine? i.e. I don't need to explicitly mention  "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0" anywhere such as  project.properties, for it all to work?  I would normally try a few things out before asking but there currently problems with jenkins and I'm unable to give it a go at the moment to see the results.

Comment: @HerrErnstvonFlübbergrübber: "if I remove that line from the manifest and copy that jar then everything should be fine?" -- it should, or at least, it used to. Ant and Eclipse at least used to pull everything from `libs/` into the compile-time build path and pour their contents into the APK. I haven't used Eclipse in over a year (since it's largely abandoned) and Ant in longer than that (since it's deader than a doornail). "I don't need to explicitly mention "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"" -- that string has no meaning to Ant.